# PHP update user - error "password didnt match"

Tags: php, mysql

since im new here in php and do not know much , my problem is i check every syntax on my code and still i get this error "password didnt match" even if the old password in the database is match in my old password field .. hope you can help me , and Sorry for my Bad formatting im still a newbie ..

here's my code .

```
<?php


$submit = strip_tags($_POST['submit']); 

$username = strtolower(strip_tags($_POST['username']));


$oldpassword = strip_tags($_POST['oldpassword']);

$newpassword = strip_tags($_POST['newpassword']);

$firstname = strip_tags($_POST['first']);

$lastname = strip_tags($_POST['last']);

$gender = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);

$address = strip_tags($_POST['address']);

$zipcode = strip_tags($_POST['zip']);

$contact = strip_tags($_POST['con']);

$email = strip_tags($_POST['mail']);

error_reporting(0);



if($submit)
{

if($username&& $oldpassword && $newpassword && $firstname && $lastname && $address && $zipcode && $contact && $email)
{

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("brightlights") or die(mysql_error());

$updatecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE username='$username'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($updatecheck);
if($count<=1)
{

if($password==($oldpassword))
{

mysql_query("UPDATE tb_user SET
                username = '$username',
                password = '$newpassword',
                Firstname = '$firstname',
                Lastname = '$lastname',
                gender = '$gender',
                address = '$address',
                zipcode = '$zipcode',
                contact = '$contact',
                email = '$email'
                WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $newpassword;
                $_SESSION['Firstname'] = $firstname;
                $_SESSION['Lastname'] = $lastname;
                $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
                $_SESSION['address'] = $address;
                $_SESSION['zipcode'] = $zipcode;
                $_SESSION['contact'] = $contact;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                session_write_close();
                echo "Succesfully Updated!";

            }else
                echo "Password not match!";
        }else
            echo "Username already Taken!";
    }else
        echo "Please fill up all form!";



}           
?>
```

Comment: Also I believe there should be a space between $username&& $oldpassword ?

Comment: i have done that already and its error still getting that message ..

Comment: @Elliot why would you use === ? If == isn't working === is definitely not going to work

Comment: can someone help me on this , i really could use some help

Comment: the $password reffers to the password in my database i have done it like this before if($_SESSION['password']==($oldpassword)) but still i get an error password not match dont know what to do

Comment: @PeeHaa Opps my bad I got abit carried away.

Comment: this is the error im getting 

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\FO\account.php on line 101
Password not match!

Comment: In this line `if($password==($oldpassword))`, you are using the variable `$password` but your variable is `$newpassword`, change it and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of retrieving the old password through the request, retrieve it from the database.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM tb_user WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count==1)
{
  $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  if($newpassword==$result["password"])
  {
......
```

As a side note. Always hash passwords when persisting/comparing them. This article describes most of it:

http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html

Comment: this is the error message im getting 

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\FO\account.php on line 101
Password not match!

Comment: Are you using what I wrote? If you successfully select 1 row(using the SQL I provided), you shouldn't have that issue. Else, print the content of $result. ex: var_dump($result);

Comment: That is because your logic is wrong. You try to update a user but disallow the update because the user already exist...

Comment: The correct logic would be to lookup the user by identity (userid) instead of username, then compare if the username differed from the one that the user already had. If the username differed, you would then check if it existed or not, if it existed, show a message; else just continue with the update.

Comment: pardon me but could you please do correct my syntax sir ? can you cite the correct syntax that i would do and do it in my code please , im only a begginer

Answer (score 0):

Just print both password and oldpassword and check the contents:

```
print($password);
print($oldpassword);

if($password==($oldpassword))
```

Why do you encapsulate the old password?

Comment: you didnt get my problems correctly let me post another sorry for my bad formating

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if($newpassword==$oldpassword)
```

instate of

```
if($password==($oldpassword))
```

I think your problem will be solved.
and try to get oldpass from database.